# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /upload.jsp at line 17

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, file-upload

**I am Using Tomcat-7 And JRE 1.8.X**

**ClassPath:** C:\Program Files\Tomcat\lib\commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Tomcat\lib\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\Program Files\Tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar;

**Woking Directory:** C:\Program Files\Tomcat\webapps\src

Trying to upload a photo from computer to *C:\Program Files\Tomcat\webapps\src\uplods\username.*

**My Code : \uplaod.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*, java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>

<%
try
{
File savedFile=new File("x.txt");
String ImageFile="";
String itemName = "";
String uname=session.getAttribute("uname").toString();
boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
if (!isMultipart)
 {%>
 <script>alert("Form enctype must be "multipart/form-data".");</script>
 <%}
else
 {
 FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
 ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
 List items = null;
  items = upload.parseRequest(request);
  Iterator itr = items.iterator();
    FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
        try
            {
            itemName = item.getName();
            savedFile = new File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"\\src\\"+"\\uploads\\"+"\\"+uname+"\\"+uname+".jpg");
            out.print(itemName);
            item.write(savedFile);
            }
        catch (Exception e){out.println("Error"+e.getMessage());}
  }
}
catch (Exception e){out.println(e.getMessage());}
response.sendRedirect("SignUpConfirmPage.htm");
%>
```

**I am getting error message like:**

```
ype Exception report

message javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:561)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.upload_jsp._jspService(upload_jsp.java:147)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(ServletFileUpload.java:68)
    org.apache.jsp.upload_jsp._jspService(upload_jsp.java:106)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(ServletFileUpload.java:68)
    org.apache.jsp.upload_jsp._jspService(upload_jsp.java:106)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**Please Help me with this.**

Comment: where does `config` `(config.getServletContext())` comes from?

Comment: could not understand your question.??

Comment: rectify me where ever necessary,

Comment: From the exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` it looks like your program is not able to detect `servlet-api.jar` .

Comment: Looks like your Tomcat installation is horribly broken.

Comment: do i need to reinstall tomcat??